# Redgate SQL Data Compare - Command LIne Output File

Tags: sql-server, comparison

I am comparing 2 databases via command line. When I execute the following command:

```
SQLDataCompare /project:"C:\CompareFiles\compare_AW1_AW2.sdc" /Include:table:[Users] /Out:"C:\Users\mthurman\Documents\outputlog.txt" /verbose
```

I get the following in my output log.txt:

Redgate Client capability version: 2
SQL Data Compare: trial, edition standard
Loading synchronization parameters from project file: C:\CompareFiles\compare_AW1_AW2.sdc
OK
Comparing database (local)\SQLEXPRESS.AW1 with database (local)\SQLEXPRESS.AW2...
Registering databases
Mapping
Comparing databases
Finished

```
Summary Information
==================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
DB1 = (local)\SQLEXPRESS.AW1
DB2 = (local)\SQLEXPRESS.AW2

Object type     Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Records      DB1 DB2 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Table           [dbo].[Users]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          2  <>  <>  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK
```

The databases have differences and running the compare through the GUI will show what they are. This output log does not show that detail. What am I missing?

Thanks, Matt